# How to get around Heroku resetting files?

Tags: python, heroku, dynamic, dyno

I have to python files that create and read text from a `.txt` file, in order for them to work they need to know the info inside of the `.txt` file.

In heroku I have a scheduler that runs one file, then the other. The big problem is that the files are reset every time to their state from the original repo. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not offer a persistent file system. You will need to store them in another service (like S3), or depending on what the contents of your files are, redesign to write and read from a database instead.

Comment: What exactly is S3?

Comment: Amazon Simple Storage Service. Here's some documentation geared towards using it with Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3